# Can't load any egg when embedding Chicken Scheme library into C project

Tags: chicken-scheme

I'm working on a chicken library that I use in a C project. When I try to load eggs (e.g. `(use intarweb)`), the runtime complains  about failing to load the egg.

```
(lldb) run
Error: (require) cannot load extension: intarweb

    Call history:

    bridge-connector.scm:6: ##sys#require       <--
Process 56172 exited with status = 70 (0x00000046)
```

I wondered whether the runtime failed to locate where the eggs are installed, so I tried setting `CHICKEN_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable with no success:

```sh
export CHICKEN_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.13.0/lib/chicken/8/"
```

I even tried using `load` directly with the full path:

```scheme
(load "/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.13.0/lib/chicken/8/intarweb.so")
```

but got the following error:

```
(lldb) run
Error: unbound variable: |\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe\x07\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00|

    Call history:

    bridge-connector.scm:6: load
```

I'm using Chicken Scheme 4 and I'm initializing the Chicken Scheme runtime as follow:

```c
#include <chicken.h>

void my_lib_initialize()
{
  C_word k = CHICKEN_run(C_toplevel);
  (void)k;
}
```

My Chicken library is built as follow:

```
csc -embedded -debug-info -d3 -J -c bridge-connector.scm
csc -embedded -debug-info -d3 -c my-lib.scm
csc -c my_lib_initialize.c
csc ./my_lib_initialize.o ./my-lib.o ./bridge-connector.o -shared -embedded -static -debug-info -d3 -o libmy-lib.dylib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-static` if you want to dynamically load extensions (which is what `use` does).

If you really want to link in intarweb statically, you'll have to compile it and all of its dependencies statically (which most CHICKEN 4 eggs don't currently do in their setup-file, so you must do it manually) and link them in, and use `(declare (uses intarweb)) (import intarweb)` instead of just `(use intarweb)`. Here's [a tutorial](https://www.foldling.org/scheme.html#compiling-statically-linked-chicken-scheme-programs-with-extensions) on how to do that. This is a bit involved in CHICKEN 4, unfortunately.

In CHICKEN 5, `chicken-install` has been rewritten to make it much easier to support static compilation of eggs. If you like, you can already [try out the latest release candidate](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/chicken-announce/2018-10/msg00003.html).  Many eggs have already been ported (including intarweb) and it should be stable enough for usage; we expect this to be the last release candidate.

Comment: I'm looking at CHICKEN 5's change log. When you say "`chicken-install` has been rewritten to make it much easier to support static compilation of eggs", are you talking about the new `-link` option?

Comment: In the changelog, there's this entry: "Static compilation of eggs is now fully supported and static versions of compiled eggs are available by default.".  If you'd like to know more, you can check out my [blog post about CHICKEN 5](https://www.more-magic.net/posts/chicken-5.html), which goes into a bit more detail about what's new in CHICKEN 5.